# Inserting Partial Row When Data Changes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm setting up a reconciliation sheet and I'm using a Macro to break up each security identifier in chunks. I have no problem coding a macro that inserts a row every time the data changes and this would work if I wasn't comparing two sets of data that aren't perfect. I need to build one Macro that inserts a row 6 columns wide two before the data that is changing 3 after and another macro that does exactly the same thing on the right-hand side but doesn't add rows across the whole worksheet effectively blowing up the last Macro I just ran. I searched far and wide and it seems most people are fine just adding a whole row as that is where the info available stops

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please include data and code.

Comment: So something like `Selection.Offset(0,-2).Resize(1,6).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`.  (But hopefully you won't use `Selection`!!)

Comment: How would you "insert a row 6 columns wide"???